Can one show $\left|\frac{2(\zeta'(x))^2-\zeta''(x)\zeta(x)}{\zeta^3(x)}\right|\leq \frac{2}{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\cap [1,\infty)$?
I have found that $\left|\frac{2(\zeta'(x))^2-\zeta''(x)\zeta(x)}{\zeta^3(x)}\right|\leq \frac{2}{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}$ for all real $x$ such that $x>1$ seems to be true. I have plotted the inequality and got this inequality holding.
Can someone help me to prove it?
here is the plot:


related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/481666/11260

$\newcommand\z\zeta\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$Yes, the inequality in question is true.
Indeed, this inequality is
$$\frac{|g(x)|}{\z(x)^3}\le\frac2{(x-1/2)^2}$$
for $x>1$, where
\begin{equation}
    g:=2{\z'}^2-\z''\z, 
\end{equation}
It was shown in the previous answer that $g$ is increasing (on $(1,\infty)$) to  $g(\infty-)=0$. So, $g<0$. So, the inequality in question can be rewritten as
$$h(x):=\frac{\z''(x)\z(x)-2{\z'(x)}^2}{\z(x)^3}\le\frac2{(x-1/2)^2}; \tag{10}\label{10}$$
here and in what follows, $x>1$ by default.
In the same mentioned answer, it was shown that
\begin{equation}
    \z''(x)\le z_2(x):=\frac{\ln^2 2}{2^x}+\frac{19}{10}\frac1{(5/2)^x}
\end{equation}
for $x\ge7/2$. Also, $z_2(x)\le\frac2{(x-1/2)^2}$ and $h\le\z''/\z^2\le\z''\le z_2$. So, \eqref{10} follows for $x\ge7/2=\frac{35}{10}$.
Also, similarly to (20) in the same mentioned answer, here we have
$$h(x)\le 
\dfrac{\Big(\dfrac1{x-1}+\ga+\tilde r_0(x)\Big)
\Big(\dfrac2{(x-1)^3}+r_2(x)\Big)
-2\Big(\dfrac2{(x-1)^2}-r_1(x)\Big)^2}
{\Big(\dfrac1{x-1}+\ga+\tilde r_0(x)\Big)^3} \\
<\frac2{(x-1/2)^2} \tag{30}\label{30}$$
for $x\in(1,\frac{13}{10}]$.
It remains to prove \eqref{10} for $x\in[\frac{13}{10},\frac{35}{10})$, which can be done by the interval method, again as in the same mentioned answer. $\quad\Box$

Thank you very much ;)

Here is a computer-based proof with Mathematica 14.1 on Windows.
NMaximize[{RealAbs[(2*D[Zeta[x], x]^2 - D[Zeta[x], {x, 2}]*Zeta[x])/
 Zeta[x]^3]*(x - 1/2)^2/2, x >= 1}, x]


{0.398781, {x -> 2.41209}}

Addition. In order to dispel doubts formulated in the comments, let us consider that optimization problem in Maple 2024, making use of a global optimizer DirectSearch
DirectSearch:-GlobalOptima(1/2*abs(2*Zeta(1, x)^2 - Zeta(2, x)*Zeta(x))*(x - 1/2)^2/Zeta(x)^3, {1 <= x}, maximize);


[0.398780684065710, [x = 2.41209275038767], 170]


I doubt that this can be considered a `proof'.

@PeterMueller: Can you kindly ground your doubt? In other case this is empty talk.

There are many reasons why this isn't a proof, the most compelling one is in Mathematica's own documentation of the function Nmaximize: `For nonlinear functions, NMaximize may sometimes find only a local maximum for certain methods'.

@PeterMueller:  Thank you for your valuable comment. I'll think about it.

@PeterMueller yes, I didn't consider it as a proof but it is a nice and helpful method to check such conjectures.

@PeterMueller: See the addition to my answer. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

@PeterMueller: The examples, where NMaximize finds a local maximum only, are complicated. The case under consideration is not of such a sort: look at the result of Plot[Evaluate[    1/2*RealAbs[(2*Zeta'[x]^2 - Zeta''[x]*Zeta[x])/Zeta[x]^3]]*(x -       1/2)^2, {x, 1, 5}] in Mathematica.

@user64494 ok, but do you have a proof that Mathematica's code cannot fail? Are you sure your plot does not contain any small-scale distorsion? There are a lot of questions to answer before a Mathematica's output can be considererd sound mathematics (I'm not saying it's not possible but it requires additional work)

The difference  between 0.3988 and 1 is too large  for "small distortions".  The rest is emotional ungrounded words.
